# How to alter a dataset to match another similar -warped- one by using the existing intersection between them?

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, latitude-longitude, utm

I have two coordinate systems for each record in my dataset. **Lat-lon coordinates** and what I suppose is **utm x-y coordinates**.
50% of my dataset only has x-y data without lat-lon, viceversa is 6%.
There is a good portion of the dataset that has both (33%) for each single record.
I wanted to know if there is a way to take advantage of the intersection (*and* maybe the x-y only part, since it's the biggest) to obtain a full dataset with only one coordinate system that makes sense. The problem is that after a little bit of preprocessing, they look "relaxed" in a different way and the intersection doesn't really match. The scatter plot shows what I believe to be a non linear, warped relationship from one system of coordinates to another. With this, I mean that normalizing them both to [0;1] and centering them to (0,0) (by subtracting the mean), gives two slightly different point distributions, and apparently a coefficient multiplication to scale one down to look like the other is not enough to get them to match completely. Looks like some more complicated relationship between the two.

I also tried to use an external library called **utm** to convert the lat-long coordinates to x-y to have a third pair of attributes (let's call it my_xy), only to find out that is not matching even one of the first two systems, instead it shows another slight warp.

Notes: When I say I do not have data from one coordinate system, assume NaN.
Furthermore, I know the warping could be a result of the fundamental geometrical differences between latlon and xy systems, but I still do not know what else I could try, if the utm conversion and the scaling did not work.

Blue: latlon, Red: original xy, Green: my_xy calculated from latlon

[image]

Comment: I suspect that this would get better attention at https://gis.stackexchange.com - but do check their terms and conditions before re-posting.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely try that if this won't get enough attention here. Actually, I thought of posting here because I am also interested in a general solution to this problem, ignoring the coordinate system _frame story_.